# How to resolve loopback find() method response ([$promise: d, $resolved: false])?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, strongloop, angular-loopback

I am new to `loopback` and angularjs REST API. I've successfully setup `mongodb` datasource, model and lb-services with `loopback`.

Below is the `angular` code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['lbServices'])
                .controller('TestController', ['$scope','Clip', function TestController($scope, Clip) {
                    $scope.allClips = Clip.find();                  
                    console.log($scope.allClips);
                }]);
```

It returns all `Clips` fine and binds it to the view. Now, the structure of model has one property with type `object`. `$scope.allClips` prints [$promise: d, $resolved: false] on console.

find() factory method in lb-services returns an instance of R which is a model name.

I tried with `Clip.find().then()` but it throws an error saying that `.then()` is not a function.

[image]

**How do I access values of a response with all of it's properties inside controller ?**

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue with below code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['lbServices'])
                .controller('TestController', ['$scope','Clip', function TestController($scope, Clip) {
                    $scope.allClips = Clip.find();
                    $scope.allClips.$promise.then(function(data){
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));                      
                    }); 
                    console.log($scope.allClips);
                }]);
```